# Changing the image src without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have faced a little problem and I feel like I'm going into circles. I'm currently working on a project where I need to update the  `<img>` src with different images after some undefined time (so I don't want to reload the images with a time interval and the image source will be different each time). I have 15 images that need to be displayed on the page, so what I want to achieve is when the image source changes in the .html file to automatically updated from the server. 
Also, I'm updating the .html file in a loop, so for each iteration there is a new image. 
This sounded pretty straightforward to me but I've stumbled upon few struggles. I know a bit of html and JavaScript but I'm completely new to jQuery and AJAX.

So far I've managed to refresh the image id using jQuery with the `.load()` method, I also tried using the `.attr()` but it didn't work for me, I still had to refresh the page to see the image i.e. send a new request from the client. What I want is for the server to make changes on the webpage independently of weather the clients send requests.

My code looks like this now:

```
    <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="cofimages">
        <img id="images" src="0.jpg" />
      </div>
      <script>        
        $("#cofimages").load("index.html");
      </script>
    </body>
```

But now the problem is that the image loads very slowly and the clients requests constantly. 
Is there any way I can solve this by different methods? Is there anyway I can preload the images so the loading time decreases? Any suggestions/ides/solutions are more than welcomed.

Comment: A side note the latest version for jQuery is 3 and .load() is probably deprecated

Comment: when is should be the images changed, based on user interaction like `click` or for time or for what ?!

Comment: the image should be changed based on the loop where I am changing the html file, so for each iteration there is a different image that needs to be shown. So no user interaction or time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use that but it's based on how you want to trigger the change

```
$(function(){
  $( "#images" ).load( "ajax/index.html #id_form_the_sended_html" );
});
```

Comment: sorry, but what exactly do you mean by `#id_form_the_sended_html`

Comment: I mean the id of the img or img attribute in the provided html

Answer (score 0):

You could have all of the images be display:none, and then .show() and .hide() them when needed.

The problem with this is the additional loading time of 15 images when the site is visited.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/d5tcq5av/

Is this what you are looking for.

```js
var imageList = [
  "http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg",
  "http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg",
  "http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.jpg",
  "http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.jpg",
  "http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/5.jpg",
  "http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/6.jpg",
  "http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/7.jpg",
  "http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/8.jpg",
  "http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/9.jpg"
]
var index = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  document.querySelector("#test").src = imageList[index];
  index++;
}, 5000)
```

```html
<img id="test" src="" />
```

Comment: Yes exactly what I need, but is there any chance to do this without a time interval?

Comment: You need some sort of trigger to switch. Change the trigger and you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try today.